# UVA Online Judge: Non-reproducible Runtime Error

Tags: c++, runtime-error

My code compiled(g++) without errors and ran without errors on my system(Macos) for sample input from the website, but is showing a Runtime Error in the online judge. Please help, I'm a new programmer. [This](https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=36) is the problem statement.

My program returns correct results for the test input data.

They haven't given the exact reason for the runtime error.
The website has this information about runtime error:

Runtime Error (RE): Your program failed during the execution (segmentation fault, floating point exception...). The exact cause is not reported to the user to avoid hacking. Be sure that your program returns a 0 code to the shell.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


using namespace std;

int main(){

    string line;

     while(getline( cin,line) && line != "" ){

         istringstream split(line);

         string kt,jt;

         getline(split, kt, ' ');
         getline(split, jt);


         int k = stoi(kt);
         int j = stoi(jt); 



        vector<int> all_cycles;

        for(int i = k; i<= j; i++){

            vector<int> cycle ;

            int temp  = i;

            while(temp != 1){

                cycle.push_back(temp);

                if(temp %2 == 0) temp = temp /2;

                else temp = (temp*3) + 1;

            }
            all_cycles.push_back(cycle.size() + 1 );
            cycle.clear();

        }       





        cout << k << " " << j << " " << *max_element(all_cycles.begin(), all_cycles.end())  << "\n";
        all_cycles.clear();

    }





    return 0;
}
```

Code Update 1:

Replaced vectors with counters.

Fixed undefined behavior if j < k.

Submitted the updated code, still Run time error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


using namespace std;

int main(){

    string line;

     while(getline( cin,line) && line != "" ){

         istringstream split(line);

         string kt,jt;

         getline(split, kt, ' ');
         getline(split, jt);


         int k = stoi(kt);
         int j = stoi(jt); 

        if(k > j) {
            int t = k;
            k = j;
            j = t;
        }



        int max_cycle = 0;

        for(int i = k; i<= j; i++){

            int  cycle = 1 ;
            int temp  = i;

            while(temp != 1){

                cycle++;

                if(temp %2 == 0) temp = temp /2;

                else temp = (temp*3) + 1;

            }
            if(cycle > max_cycle) max_cycle = cycle;

        }       


        cout << k << " " << j << " " <<  max_cycle << "\n";


    }





    return 0;
}
```

Code Update 2:

I replaceed string parsing the input by using formatted input and solved the newline detection problem by copying the next character of input from the streambuffer to a variable and checked if it is a newline.

This updated code seems to get rid of the Runtime Error and Now it is an output error.
Which I should be able to solve through formatting my output.
So it seems that stoi in my earlier code  might have been throwing an exception during runtime.Thank you @walnut for pointing that out.

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main(){

    int k, j;
    int eofile = 0;

     while(cin >> k >> j && !eofile ){


        streambuf * pbuf = cin.rdbuf();
        char ch = pbuf->snextc();
        if(ch == '\n')  eofile = 1;

        if(k > j) {
            int t = k;
            k = j;
            j = t;
        }

        int max_cycle = 0;

        for(int i = k; i<= j; i++){

            int  cycle = 1 ;
            int temp  = i;

            while(temp != 1){

                cycle++;

                if(temp %2 == 0) temp = temp /2;

                else temp = (temp*3) + 1;
            }
            if(cycle > max_cycle) max_cycle = cycle;
        }       

        cout << k << " " << j << " " <<  max_cycle << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If there is a better way to get formatted input and also detect newline, please tell me how to do it.

Comment: It might be helpful to include the runtime error in your question.

Comment: You don't need to save an entire cycle to determine how long it is, you can keep a counter. Similarly, you don't need to save all the lengths, you can keep track of the longest one.

Comment: Also, `int k = 0, j = 0; while (cin >> k >> j) { ...` is much simpler than splitting and converting by hand.

Comment: Thats what I did at first @molbdnilo, but I hit a problem of not being able to stop cin when the input was empty.

Comment: @molbdnilo The counter you mentioned is much better, I'll update the code, Thanks.

Comment: You never need to call `.clear()` if you don't intend to reuse the vector. Your program has undefined behavior if `temp` overflows. Please provide the input for which the program fails.

Comment: @walnut I was using the vector to store new data every loop, that is the reason I used .clear(). I updated the code with a suggestion I received . The website is not giving me the reason or the data which it is failing on , but the program runs on test data in my system with no problems.

Comment: You don't need `.clear()`. You are using a *new* vector in each iteration. `cycle` is declared inside the loop, so in each loop iteration it is a different vector. The clear is redundant. Similarly `all_cycles.clear();` is redundant. Without knowing the input there isn't really any way to help you. The first code has undefined behavior if `j < k`, if `temp` overflows and it will throw an exception if `stoi` fails or if you run out of memory. These are all situations that you could add tests for in the code.

Comment: @walnut Thanks for all the valuable information , I will start working on all your suggestions.

Comment: At a very high level, part of what you would need in order to reproduce the same issue encountered by the judge are at least two missing pieces. You don't know the inputs they are sending to your program. You also (maybe?) don't know the exact compiler version and compiler OPTIONS. You can address these issues, respectively, by: (1) devising a corpus of difficult/large/chaotic inputs you can test with, and by (2) compiling your code with different g++ flags, to get different optimizations enabled/disabled. I hope this general advice is useful.

Comment: Thanks @pestophagous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem :

Program run without any errors with runtime : 0.330s

The runtime error was solved when I replaced the stoi() function with input formatting.

Finally there was an output error because I was flipping k and j to prevent undefined behavior when j < k, which I solved by formatting the output accordingly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>


using namespace std;

int main(){

    string line;

     while(getline( cin,line) && line != "" ){

         istringstream split(line);
         int k,j;

        split >> k >> j; 

        int flip = 0;


        if(k > j) {
            flip = 1;
            int t = k;
            k = j;
            j = t;
        }


        int max_cycle = 0;

        for(int i = k; i<= j; i++){

            int  cycle = 1 ;
            int temp  = i;

            while(temp != 1){

                cycle++;

                if(temp %2 == 0) temp = temp /2;

                else temp = (temp*3) + 1;

            }
            if(cycle > max_cycle) max_cycle = cycle;

        }       

        if(!flip) cout << k << " " << j << " " <<  max_cycle << "\n";
        else cout << j << " " << k << " " <<  max_cycle << "\n";


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks to everyone for all the help.